# (Rails) Trying to show the correct item when someone clicks on the link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I'm still fairly new to Rails but, currently I have been working on a Rails project for bit now and my last issue with it is when someone clicks on a specific recipe it only shows the very first one a user ever created. I've accessed my database through my console to see if these recipes are saving and they are but when I click on any of the links to a specific recipe it still shows the incorrect one and it won't show the recipe name either.

Here's my recipe controller

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_login

def show
  @recipe=Recipe.find_by(params[:name])
  binding.pry
end

def index
    @recipes =Recipe.all
    #binding.pry
end

def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  @recipe.ingredients.build(name: "name")
  
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

  @recipe.save

  #binding.pry
  redirect_to recipes_path
end

  private
    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:id,:name,:content, ingredients_attributes: [
        :recipe_id,
        :user_id,
        :name,
        :quantity
        ]
      )
    end
```

end

Index Page

```
<h1>All Recipes</h1>
<ul>
<% @recipes.each do |recipes| %>
<li><%= link_to recipes.name, recipes %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Show Page

```
<% @recipe.name do |r| %>
<h2> <%= r.name %></h2>
<h2> <%= r.content %></h2>

<%end%>

<h3>Ingredients</h3>

<ul>
 <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
 <li><%= "#{ingredient.name} X #{ingredient.quantity}" %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your `show` method it's either one of those

```
Recipe.find_by(name: params[:name])
# or ...
Recipe.find(params[:id])
```

...depending on what setup you got going in your routes, the second one is the usual Rails way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code. In your `RecipesController`, change the `show` action code to this:

```
def show
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end
```

In your `index.html.erb` view, change the code that iterates through your recipes to this:

```
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
  <li><%= link_to recipes.name, recipe %></li>
<% end %>
```

And finally, in your `show.html.erb` view, change the code to this:

```
<h2><%= @recipe.name %></h2>
<h2><%= @recipe.content %></h>

<h3>Ingredients</h3>

<ul>
  <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
   <li><%= ingredient.name %> X <%= ingredient.quantity %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

#### Summary of the changes

In the `show` action of the `RecipesController`, you search for the recipe by the id passed in from the view. That id comes from this line:

```
<%= link_to recipe.name, recipe %>
```

`recipe` gets `to_param` called on it, which returns the id of that particular recipe which you then use in the `show` action of the `RecipesController` to find the correct recipe.

In the `index.html.erb` view, you iterate through all of the recipes, via the `@recipes` variable, and output each recipe. Since you are outputting each recipe, you normally use `recipe` instead of `recipes` as the block variable.

In the `show.html.erb` view, you don't need to iterate through all recipes because you only have one recipe from the show action of the `RecipesController`. That recipe is stored in the `@recipe` variable, so you can use that variable directly in the view.